# Class creation [Begineer in programming]

Tags: c++, class

It's my first code with classes. the dev c++ compiler find 4 errors so i need a help. I think there's something wrong in my concept may be 
This was the Header file "complex.h"

```
class complex{
  public:
         bool ReadComplex();
  private:
          double real;
          double imag;
  };
```

---

This is the .cpp file

```
#include "complex.h"
#include <iostream.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

bool complex::ReadComplex()
 { cout<<"Enter the real part";
   cin>>real;
   cout<<"Enter the imaginary part";
   cin>>imag;
   return true;
                       }
```

---

and i got 4 errors

C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/mingw32/bits/c++config.h:57: error: expected unqualified-id before "namespace"

C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/mingw32/bits/c++config.h:57: error: expected `,' or`;' before "namespace"

C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/mingw32/bits/c++config.h:61: error: expected namespace-name before ';' token

C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/mingw32/bits/c++config.h:61: error: `' is not a namespace

---

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Please add the compiler error messages to your question.

Comment: would be useful to know some of the errors at least...

Comment: You have 55 errors, and you didn't post a single one.

Comment: It makes no sense whatsoever to ask for help with errors and not even state what errors you are getting.

Comment: If you edit the code in the question, **please** state what you changed! Now the error messages is not for the code you have shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first code with classes should be:

```
class complex{
  };

int main()
  {
    return(0);
  }
```

Seriously. Get this to work, with no compiler warnings. Then add complexity a little at a time, and never add to code that doesn't work.

Answer (score 6):

class definition should end with a `;`

```
class complex
{
    // ....
} ;
//^ missing semi-colon
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the semicolon at the end of the class definition:

```
class complex{

}; //<------- here put a semicolon
```

Answer (score 2):

- Make sure you put the class in your own named namespace, or else not say `using namespace std`. There's a `std::complex` type, and although you don't include its header, implementors are allowed to include it themselves in any of the standard headers.
- End your class definition with a semicolon: `class complex { /* ... */ };`
- Don't use `<iostream.h>`. Use `<iostream>`. Things there are in the `std::` namespace, by the way.
- What's `<Math.h>`? Is it some 3rd party library you're using that's installed outside your project tree? If it's your own code or inside your project tree then use double quotes, not angle brackets. Double quotes ask the compiler to search for the code in your tree, whereas angle brackets ask the compiler to look in system directories.
- Are you sure the standard math header won't do? Take a look at the `<cmath>` header.

You should also

- make `GetReal()` and `GeatImag()` const functions. If the `Get` or `Set` counterparts don't do anything special you should throw them away and set the member data public. This because less code is less bugs.
- You should take parameters as const references whenever it makes sense. Like in `complex::Add()`, for example, which should be a const function too if it doesn't change the object.

Comment: i tried math.h and it works in my compiler <cmath> and <iostream> give error without .h

Comment: @eslam everything in `<iostream>`, `<cmath>` and other standard headers is inside the `std` namespace. `<iostream.h>` is deprecated, don't use it. Similarly, you should use `<cmath>` and not `<math.h>` in C++ code. Just make sure you say `std::cout` and not `cout`. Similarly for anything else you use from these headers.